# Paypal Adaptive payments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paypal, activemerchant

I am using PayPal Adaptive Payments in a rails 3 application. I'm wondering if this the best approach or if there's better way to use PayPal Adaptive Payments?

=> Install Active merchant plugin latest version

```
https://github.com/sijokg/active_merchant(https://github.com/sijokg/active_merchant.git)
```

=> Create a Object for paypal adaptive gateway

```
    gateway = ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalAdaptivePaymentGateway.new( :login =>        "divya_xxxxxx_biz_api1.yahoo.com",:password => "XXXXXXXX", :signature => "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",:appl_id => "APP-80W284485P519543T" ) 



   ss= gateway.pay params[:donor][:amount].to_i , 'foobar@yahoo.com', :ip => request.remote_ip,   
     :sender_email => "foobar@yahoo.com",
     :tracking_id => tracking_id,
     :pay_key => '24',
     :return_url =>"http://myapp.heroku.com,                                              :cancel_url=>
```

"http://foofoo.heroku.com ,
  :ipn_notification_url => "http://foofoo.heroku.com/paypal_ipn"

=> It returns paykey , using this paykey I redirect to below urls based on requiremnet

```
    redirect_to "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=#{ ss.params['pay_key']}" 
    redirect_to "https://www.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=#{ ss.params['pay_key']}"
```

=> It goes to paypal site and compelte transaction with email or visa card and return .

=> If I use sandbox account , It needs to login in sandbox account

=> It send " Paypal Ipn " to my site .

=> Tranaction complete .

***  This process takes much time because it is two steps process . If it is not correct,  pelase suggest any alternative solution with paypal adaptive payments .

Comment: Railscasts has just released paypal processing for a Rails application. Might be a different method, but might prove useful. Unfortunately it's on the Railscast Pro side of things, and requires a subscription. Might be worth checking into.

Answer (score 1):

I use https://github.com/tc/paypal_adaptive and it's working great for me.  Yes, it's a 2 step process.  You need to get the payKey from PayPal then either 1) redirect the user or 2) kick of the lightbox flow with PAYPAL.apps.DGFlow, specified here: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APCommands